# Reading in data from two-valued matrix Fortran90

Tags: file-io, matrix, fortran, fortran90

I have a Fortran code that does random operations on a certain matrix of 1's and -1's for a number of iterations per your choice. Afterwards it prints me a data file with its output so I can plot it in gnuplot.

Sometimes the number of iterations is insufficient. As a result I would like to use the output data file as input to my code to make more iterations on it.

The data file looks like this:

```
# some text to skip

1   1   -1   1   -1   -1   1   . . . 
-1   1   -1   -1   1   -1   1   . . . 
-1   -1   1   1   -1   1   -1   . . . 
.      .                        .
.               .               . 
.                         .     .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

with i rows and j columns.

So what I need to do is skip the first line, then make a do-loop over i and j till their maximum value while skipping the spaces in between the 1's and -1's, and allocate their respective values to an allocatable matrix A(:,:) in my code.

Could anybody perhaps help me with what is the best way to achieving this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How much help do you need ?  Your question could be read to imply that you know no Fortran whatsoever.  If you do know any Fortran show us your best effort at coding this for yourself.

Comment: Well, yes, I am a Fortran novice, and I try to adjust a code of someone else. I have python experience but to fortran I am new. I thought to just ask people that may know, so that I can learn more about the syntax. Not foreseeing any resistance though...

Comment: Hi High Performance Mark, I have answered my own question. I wanted to post it here but I am only allowed to do so 8 hours after asking my question. I will do that later. Thanks for your comment though.